# Rails 3.1. What's the easiest way to make chaining dropdown selects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I was trying to make work this:
http://chainselects.hypermediasoft.com/

But got error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant ChainSelectsHelper
```

So i have to make some break and ask community - is there any easy way to make chaining select boxes for my application forms?

UPDATE:
Maybe i should make editions in some config files? I can see thist ChainSelectsHelper in vendor/plugins/ChainSelects/lib/app/helpers/chain_selects_helper.rb. But why my application can't see this? Any assets pipeline configs needed?

And got this error in model:

```
undefined method `acts_as_chainable' for #<Class:0x007fe387542780>
```

Comment: after you make changes to your controller, have you restart the rails server?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems that you did not add this in the controller:

```
include ChainSelectsHelper
```

Keep in mind that modifications have to be made to both model and controller, as stated [here](http://chainselects.hypermediasoft.com/step_by_step_guide).

Comment: No, i added this to my controller:  
include ChainSelectsHelper  
class ProductionYearsController < ApplicationController

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the steps in the step by step guide? Did you add the `acts_as_chainable` in your models? Have you defined the relationships between them?

Comment: Absolutely sure, i wrote my updates. Maybe some assets pipeline configs needed, or something?

Comment: Could it be that the stuff from vendor is not autoloaded anymore, in Rails 3.1? Try adding this to your `application.rb`: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/vendor)`

Comment: Added, but nothing changed :(